# Specify Credentials in XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, credentials, xmlreader

I am attempting to access an XML feed (with username and password) by using XMLReader.
Formerly, I had integrated the credentials into the url (e.g. `http://username:password@mysite.com`); however, this is not working now.

I get `'XPath query failed for bio'` at the final check in my code.

Would it be possible to specify the username/password in XMLReader?

Thanks for any leads.

My code (edited to include my Curl code):

```
<?php
$secondary_user_id = "jsmith";
$url_bio = "http://username:password@mysite.com";

//
$a_username='username';
$a_password='password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_bio);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $a_username . ':' . $a_password);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$a_error = curl_error($ch);
echo '<br>'.$a_error.'<br>';
curl_close($ch);
//



$reader = new XMLReader();
//$reader->open($url_bio);
$reader->XML($result);
while ($reader->read()) 
{

if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Users') 
    {
            //the code works to this point  
            echo 'success<br>';
            $node = $reader->expand();
            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');//
            $n = $doc->importNode($node,true);
            $doc->appendChild($n);
            //$xml_bio_report = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(),true));//
            $xml_bio_report =  simplexml_import_dom($n);//

        $xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
        $xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('dmu','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/user-metadata');

          //echo $xml_bio_report->Users->User;


        $xml_bio_report_abbrev = $xml_bio_report->xpath('//User[@SecondaryID="'.$secondary_user_id.'"]');

        if ($xml_bio_report_abbrev){
            echo '<h1>'.$xml_bio_report_abbrev[0]['username'].'</h1>';
            echo '<h1>'.$xml_bio_report_abbrev[0]['SecondaryID'].'</h1>';

        } else {
            echo 'XPath query failed for bio';  
        }

}
}
?>
```

Comment: The login is not the responsibility of XMLReader. Essentially it just calls file_get_contents(), which makes for a very simplistic HTTP client. If you need proper authentication consider using cURL (or a library thereof) to send the required HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated my code to show my tests with cURL.  It is successful to a point.  XMLReader is reading the cURL result, but is there a problem in the simplexml_import_dom?

Comment: @Dormilich not `file_get_contents()` but `fopen()`. It opens a stream and reads it part by part.

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader::open() uses the PHP streamwrapper. Here is a function called `libxml_set_streams_context()` that allows to set the context for the next open/load call.

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($url_bio);
//...
```